# Consume WCF Service from silverlight 4

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, cross-domain

I have a solution which contain a Silverlight 4 project and a WCF class library project.
and I add a service refrence to the WCF service in the Silverlight project (WCF is not published on IIS). I try to call the service from the Silverlight project, it gives me the following exception:

> An error occurred while trying to make a request to URI `http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/CustomWcfService/MyService/`. This could be due to attempting to access a service in a cross-domain way without a proper cross-domain policy in place, or a policy that is unsuitable for SOAP services. You may need to contact the owner of the service to publish a cross-domain policy file and to ensure it allows SOAP-related HTTP headers to be sent. This error may also be caused by using internal types in the web service proxy without using the InternalsVisibleToAttribute attribute. Please see the inner exception for more details.

I try to solve this problem by adding the following two files into WCF library project

1) clientaccesspolicy.xml which has the following xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="SOAPAction">
        <domain uri="*"/>
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

2) crossdomain.xml which contains the following xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy> <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

then build the WCF project and update service refrence in silverlight project but the same exception still exist.

What should I do to handle this exception? Should I publish the service? And is this considered self hosting ??

Comment: Remove the existing reference manually and add it with a new name!

Comment: Where did you add the clientaccesspolicy.xml file on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Put your clientaccesspolicy.xml file to the root of iis. In example to c:\inetpub\wwwroot